# XML ElementTree in ArcPy consuming WMTS XML

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, xml, wmts

How do I work with the xml Element Tree to obtain the ScaleDenominator parent where ows:Identifier = default028mm?

With a fair bit of swearing I have managed to hack my way into all of the WMTS Scale's, I  noticed that the OGC ones list first, I've taken advantage of this. But I want to do it properly and read the OGC Scales only. Alas, I've hit a brick wall. Any ideas?

```
import arcpy
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

WMTS = urllib.urlopen("http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml")
print "Started"

import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse(WMTS,parser=None)
root = tree.getroot()
test = 0
MaxScale = 600000 #600K No Scales Above

for ScaleDenominator in root.iter('{http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0}ScaleDenominator'):
    Scale = float(ScaleDenominator.text)
    ScaleCon = ((Scale/90.7144671432)*95.9999999999)
    print 'WMST: ', ScaleDenominator.text
    print 'Esri: ', ScaleCon
    if test == 0:
        test = (ScaleCon+1)   
    if test > ScaleCon:
        print 'OGC028:', ScaleCon
        test = (ScaleCon+1)
        if ScaleCon < MaxScale:
            print '< OGC028:', ScaleCon
```

**WMTS XML:**
[National Map USGS Topo WMTS XML](http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml)

[image: Example]

Comment: I make a correction: the solution with ElementTree and alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ElementTree, the solution is ([urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) is deprecated, use [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or better, the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module):

```
import urllib2
WMTS = urllib2.urlopen("http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml")
tree = et.parse(WMTS)
for elem in tree.iter(tag='{http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0}ScaleDenominator'):
     print float(elem.text)
559082264.029 279541132.014 139770566.007 69885283.0036 34942641.5018 17471320.7509 8735660.37545 4367830.18772 2183915.09386 1091957.54693 545978.773466 272989.386732 136494.693366 68247.3466831 34123.6733415 17061.8366712 559082264.029 279541132.014 139770566.007 69885283.0036 34942641.5018 17471320.7509 8735660.37545 4367830.18772 2183915.09386 1091957.54693 545978.773466 272989.386733 136494.693366 68247.3466832 34123.6733416 17061.8366708 8530.9183354 4265.4591677 2132.72958385
```

{http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0} is a [XML namespace](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp). To "eliminate" the namespaces, you can use:

- [lxml](http://lxml.de/) that supports namespace prefixes with `xpath` (not pure Python)
- [py-dom-xpath](https://code.google.com/p/py-dom-xpath/), a pure Python module with `xpath`

```py
import xml.dom.minidom
WMTS = urllib2.urlopen("http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml")
import xpath
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(WMTS)
context = xpath.XPathContext(doc)
context.namespaces
{u'xsi': u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', u'xlink': u'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', u'ows': u'http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1', u'gml': u'http://www.opengis.net/gml'}
context.findvalues('//ScaleDenominator', doc)
[u'5.590822640285016E8', u'2.7954113201425034E8', u'1.3977056600712562E8', u'6.988528300356235E7', u'3.494264150178117E7', u'1.7471320750890587E7', u'8735660.375445293', u'4367830.187722647', u'2183915.0938617955', u'1091957.5469304253', u'545978.7734656851', u'272989.38673237007', u'136494.69336618503', u'68247.34668309252', u'34123.67334154626', u'17061.836671245605', u'559082264.0287178', u'279541132.0143589', u'139770566.0071794', u'69885283.00358972', u'34942641.50179486', u'17471320.75089743', u'8735660.375448715', u'4367830.187724357', u'2183915.093862179', u'1091957.546931089', u'545978.7734655447', u'272989.3867327723', u'136494.6933663862', u'68247.34668319309', u'34123.67334159654', u'17061.83667079827', u'8530.918335399136', u'4265.459167699568', u'2132.729583849784']
for value in context.findvalues('//ScaleDenominator', doc):
    print float(value) 
559082264.029
279541132.014
....
```

- [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffer318ae&utm_medium=twitter), a pure Python module. It is easy to install (even in ArcPy, one file)

[xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffer318ae&utm_medium=twitter) converts XML files to Python dictionaries (standard [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), dictionary that remembers the order that keys were inserted): you process the XML tree with only lists and dictionaries

```
import requests
WMTS = requests.get("http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml")
import xmltodict
tree = xmltodict.parse(WMTS.content)
print tree.keys()
[u'Capabilities']
print tree[u'Capabilities'].keys()
[u'@xmlns', u'@xmlns:ows', u'@xmlns:xlink', u'@xmlns:xsi', u'@xmlns:gml', u'@xsi:schemaLocation', u'@version', u'ows:ServiceIdentification', u'ows:OperationsMetadata', u'Contents', u'ServiceMetadataURL']
 for i in tree[u'Capabilities'][u'Contents'][u'TileMatrixSet']:
     for tile in i[u'TileMatrix']:
          print tile[u'ows:Identifier'], float(tile[u'ScaleDenominator'])
  0 559082264.029
  1 279541132.014
  2 139770566.007
  3 69885283.0036
  .....
```

Comment: gene, this is great stuff. However I'm rolling out a tool to hundreds of global ArcGIS Users. They will have python, but xmltodict will be an issue with our IT folks.